# how to create auto atttendance system using filemaker

Tags: filemaker

Hi i am new to filemaker, i am interested to learn and create an attendance system using filemaker. the way i like to do it is using the solution provided in filemaker ( Time Cards ). i would like my code to capture the timestamp of the user when ever the user enter his/her id and filemaker will automatically store the timestamp of that particular event. also the solution should be able to detect if it is already capture any previous time already entered by the same user. Sorry for my explaination. i hope its clear and understandable by you guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you are trying to do sounds very possible and not too difficult. May I suggest that you give it a try and come back and ask one specific how-to question for each problem you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

If the users are logging into the system (username and password), you can accomplish this by running a script on open (login).

That would work like:

1. go to tracking table (table made of timestamp and accountName field)
2. set error capture on
3. perform find - accountName = get(accountName)
4. if get(lastError) = 401 [this shows there are no records from this user], create new record, set field timestamp = get(currentTimestamp), set field accountName = get(accountName)
5. else [you can exit application, show dialog, or skip adding a new record if they entered previous data]
6. endif, then script whatever else you need to do onOpen.

If your users are entering in a temp field to log in against a user table, it's a similar step, you just need to grab $accountName as a variable to use in the find.